# Does RDMS Violate OOP

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I Want To Design OOP With Existing Data Base I have 
 Header,Details,linking Tables,Stored Proc which Retrieve 
 and calculate From Many Tables And Do Aggregates etc,
 Am confused How To Convert All The Mess To OOP ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear what exactly your question is at the moment - please refer to [ask].

Comment: Tips And Hints To Clarify My Confusion

Answer (score 0):

A Relational Database (RDB) and Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) are different paradigms and techniques of each reflects a different purpose. A RDB is intended to efficiently store data in tables and quickly extract data and relations, while OOP is intended reflect the composition and abstraction of objects seen in the real-world. Being that the purpose of each is different, there is a logical gap between the two, but there is a great deal of work that has been done on converting from RDB to OOP and vice-versa.

This technique is called [Object-Relational Mapping (ORM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). There are a standard set of patterns and techniques that are used in ORM that can easily convert RDB data to OOP and vice-versa, but the specific techniques are beyond the scope of this post. In addition, [Patterns of Enterprise Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) has a very important list of techniques for bridging the gap between relational data and OOP, including:

- [Unit of Work Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)
- [Query Object Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html)
- [Repository Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

In practice, these techniques are so common that many languages or popular frameworks have already codified these patterns, removing the need to manually implement them in a project. For example, in Java, there is [Java Database Connectivity (JDBC)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and [Spring JDBC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/). The specific framework and tools will depend on the language, but most modern languages have a database (specifically relational database) mapping tools that remove the need to write tedious procedures to extract and store data. If you are interested, there is a list (albeit not comprehensive) of ORMs by language at [List of object-relational mapping software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software).

---

**Suggestion**: Read and understand the common practices of ORM and then select a ORM or database abstraction framework that suits the need of your project.